# Start RUP elaboration phase when Inception is not finished yet

Tags: rup

Question for RUP (Rational Unified Process) experts.

We are going to have an inception phase on the project where we will provide project management plan, software requirements specification (SRS), etc.

However, according to the methodology, we should not start the elaboration phase until artifacts from the Inception phase are accepted by the client/stakeholders.

I'd like to utilize resources as much as I can, so my idea is to provide the artifacts for acceptance, start elaboration phase right away, and then, during the Acceptance phase, do some improvements to design documents if such are needed. This lets me to save some time and not just find ways for acceptance.

Would that work? Or there are other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a risk management question, i.e., no one answer will cover all the possible risk scenarios we face on projects jumping from one phase to the next.  The answer you are looking for lies in your risk assessment of your project at this time.  Some questions you need to answer are: 1) is this project generally high risk; 2) how involved were your customer stakeholders during the preceding phase; 3) is this environment a highly politically charged one with a high degree of internal stakeholder fighting; 4) if rejection occurs or there is a lot of changes required from the preceding phase, how much rework will be required in the successor phase or can you still eek out value no matter if you receive a rejection or a ton of changes; 5) if you wait for acceptance, how much can you spend in holding costs for project resources as they sit idle?

There are likely more risk questions to ask here but maybe this can get you started.

RUP is part of our methods we use in my firm (I work for IBM) and there is no explicit rule that I have read in our methods that dictate how we move from one phase to the next; however, we typically keep going.  Our mitigation to the risk is stakeholder involvement so that we are very confident we have approval with minimal changes at draft delivery.  This is not to say it works perfectly all the time but such is life.

Comment: Great, thanks, that what I thought. Yes, risks management will work here. I will see how requirements gathering will go. Then it will be clear how risky is to continues without waiting...